# iPhone localization stuck on russian

Tags: iphone, localization, default

I am currently localizing an app for a client, we already had EFIGS in, and are now adding portugese and russian. Everything fine with the portugese, but as soon as I add ru.lproj to the project, the app will always run in russian no matter what the device language settings are ... anybody ever experienced this? any ideas? tips?